# How to handle error responses from in any step of a completable future chain?

Tags: java, asynchronous, httpresponse, completable-future

I've got a chain of completable futures, each of them making an API call, depending on the previous result. I am trying to understand how to process error responses in each chain. If any step gives me an HTTP error, say bad request, I should break the chain and show the error message. I am thinking of throwing a runtime exception in case an error comes up, and then append exceptionally() at the end of the CF chain. Is there a better way of doing it? Can I avoid throwing exceptions in case of failure responses?

Answer (score 0):

[Guide to Completable Future](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)

> For error-handling in a chain of asynchronous computation steps, throw/catch idiom had to be adapted in a similar fashion.
>
> Instead of catching an exception in a syntactic block, the CompletableFuture class allows you to handle it in a special handle method. This method receives two parameters: a result of a computation (if it finished successfully) and the exception thrown (if some computation step did not complete normally).

Comment: Thanks for the guide Abra! I've read it before, and I understand the usage of the handle method. However, my use case is slightly different. I need to handle error response and not the exceptions. My question is if there is a better way to handle error response rather than throwing a runtime exception, everytime I encounter an error response. Does this make it clear?

Comment: I see that I misunderstood your question. You want to know how to handle HTTP error responses and not `java.lang.Exception`s.